# Truth Table- is this correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need someone to help me workout the last column of this truth table as I don't know how to do it.

[image]

Not sure if this is correct but if it isn't then please correct me.
[truth table attempted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6KWh.jpg)

Comment: You already know the values of each piece of the expression so all you have to do is substitute those values in. Is there any specific symbol you don't understand?

Comment: @ImHereSometimes im usually always confused with how to fix the last columns, do i have to look at the P v Q, Q > R and the ¬R? If they are all true would that mean the first row is true? and if one of them have a false would that mean its false?

Comment: The idea is that you look at the values already computed for $P \lor Q$, $Q \implies R$, and $\lnot R$, and then use these to evaluate the last expression. So for the first row, you would have by substitution $(T \land  T \land F) \implies T$, which simplifies to $F \implies T$, which is false, so you put an $F$ in the first row and so on.

Comment: @ImHereSometimes Ohh right  i think its starting to sink in. If all three of them expressions are true then its a true value but if they are not all true then its a false value right?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $P \implies Q$? It is true except when $P$ is false and $Q$ is true.

Comment: yeah i know the definition of P > Q (if P then Q)

Comment: The values in the column for $Q \to R$ are wrong; check with the t-t for $\to$.

Comment: The values in the column for $\lnot R$ are **wrong** ! The negation will "reverse" the truth value.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i've changed the table around and can you confirm if it is right please. https://imgur.com/a/V9Fic

Comment: Now it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You might try breaking the expression into smaller pieces, and computing a column of the truth table for each piece separately.

For example, you have a column for $(P \vee Q)$ and one for $(Q \rightarrow R)$, so you can quickly compute a column of results for:

$$A \equiv (P \vee Q) \wedge (Q\rightarrow R)$$

which is a piece of your answer. Then, because you know $A\equiv (P\vee Q)\wedge (Q\rightarrow R)$ and you know $\neg R$, you can easily compute a column of results for:

$$B \equiv A \wedge \neg R = (P \vee Q)\wedge (Q\rightarrow R)\wedge \neg R.$$

Finally, you can compute a column for $B \rightarrow P$, which is the original problem you're trying to solve.

---

Another strategy would be to use algebra to simplify the final expression so that it's easier to calculate, but I think this strategy is easiest.

Comment: its my first time doing discrete maths so all this seems very complicated for me. How would i know the first row is true or false?
Would i have to check the table that if (P v Q) and (Q > R) is true in order for the first row to be true?

Comment: If you're talking about making a column for $A \equiv (P\vee Q)\wedge(Q\rightarrow R)$, then yes --- you just check that $(P\vee Q)$ is true and $(Q\rightarrow R)$ is true.  Because you've already made a column in your table for $(P\vee Q)$, you can just look that up; same for $(Q\rightarrow R)$.